# JavaFx TableView CRUD for large database tables

Tags: java, database, javafx, tableview, large-data

I'm looking for sample apps or documentation for displaying a large table in JavaFx TableView , without loading the entire table into memory beforehand.  CRUD capabilities would be nice, too, though I can write this myself if necessary.

All the examples I have found pre-load data into a an observable list (in memory, I assume), which I can't do for, say, 5 million records!

I have worked in Java Swing with table models that get their data from JDBC ResultSets, is there something similar I can do for JavaFx TableView?  I also added my own sort and column layout persistence in Swing, and am looking to do something similar in JavaFx.

This may be a "beginner" question, or it's possible that I missed something simple while scouring through the JavaFx info.

Comment: Take a look at the [datafx framework](http://www.javafxdata.org/) and see if that assists.

Comment: I did find DataFx before posting the question, documentation/examples are slim, and from the description of the classes, there is a JDBC data source class, whose superclasses only have a get() and next(), no kind of seek or getrowat(x,y), so it somewhat leads me to believe the library reads everything into memory.  I haven't looked at the source code to verify this, though, so if anyone knows more, please comment here!

Answer (score 0):

Each TableView must has a model class. you can easily set your model class to table view.

For example you have class Student with (id,name,avg)

define an ObservableList of Student just like

```
ObservableList<Student> stdList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

then set the list to the table view by

```
tableView.setDate(stdList);
```

and Now you can do anything you imagine (CRUD) on the list.

Comment: This doesn't really address the problem of not having to load all the records into memory. Also I think .setDate() isn't what you intended.